# JSON GET from Itbook API

Tags: c#, json, api, get

EDIT: I've found that this is JArray, and I need JObject [], but I need some idea on how to make it possible.

I have problem where I can not get data from API - https://api.itbook.store/

I get error when trying url - https://api.itbook.store/1.0/ - System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.'

And when I try to load just few books like in example on page with this url - https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/mongodb - I get this message: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: StartObject. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

```
    public KnjiznicaRepo()
    {

        string url = "https://api.itbook.store/1.0/";
        string json = CallRestMethod(url);

        JArray jsonObject = JArray.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject item in jsonObject)
        {
            knjiznicas.Add(new Knjiznica
            {
                NazivKnjige = (string)item.GetValue("title"),
                Podnaziv = (string)item.GetValue("subtitle"),
                ISBN13 = (string)item.GetValue("isbn13"),
                Cijena = (string)item.GetValue("price"),
                Link = (string)item.GetValue("url")
            });
        }
    }
    public static string CallRestMethod(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webrequest.Method = "GET";
        webrequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        Encoding enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), enc);
        string result = string.Empty;
        result = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        webresponse.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the url to `MongoDB` books. And parse the output as `JObject` instead of `JArray`. Then treat `books` field inside as an array:

```
    ...
        string url = "https://api.itbook.store/1.0/search/mongodb";
        string json = CallRestMethod(url);

        var o = JObject.Parse(json);

        foreach (JObject item in o.GetValue("books"))
        {
            ...
```

This is very simple example, it's better to add error handling.